# why this code dont work? why do i need the return type to be a reference?

Tags: c++

```
ostream operator<<(ostream& os, class n);
```

I need to know whats happening inside and why it doesnt work if the return type is not a reference. And I need some links to good articles about istreams and ostreams that help me understand them (not too complicated articles please :D:D) thank you very much.

UPDATE 1: please remember to share links for articles so I can learn more about ostream and istream objects. thank you.

Comment: There is some information on iostream programming on the Microsoft website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22z6066f(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: thank you. im gonna check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream`'s copy constructor is private - which means you cannot create a copy of a stream object.

Each stream has an associated underlying buffer - which handles the reads/writes (for example `filebuf` manages the reads/writes to files). If you were to make a copy of the stream, what do you propose to do with this underlying buffer? You cannot copy it, because then you would have two buffers (maintaining separate positional information - e.g. where it's written to) - imagine the havoc... If you "move" it - i.e. transfer the ownership, there is the potential that you could quite conceivably loose the buffer (if copied to some scoped stream - say you pass it by value to a function and don't return it), then what happens? It's for complications like these, it makes sense to make this object non-copyable...

Comment: but where am i copying the ostream?? where in the function im trying to make the copy?? im a beginner i need step by step explanation.

Comment: @jose, in the return, when you return, what happens (according your declaration) is that a temporary ostream object gets constructed with the ostream you are returning. I'm guessing you know what happens when you pass the `ostream` in by reference rather than value? think the same in reverse for return...

Comment: mmmm so everytime i return some object from a function. the constructor of that object is called????

Comment: to be precise, the copy constructor. But be wary, you cannot always return references either (i.e. you cannot return by reference an object that is local to that function - as when you go out of scope, that object is effectively out of scope and your reference could access to crap). I suggest you revisit your C++ book and look carefully at functions and returning results from functions...

Comment: Hey jose, put a '&' with your return type: ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, class n); Be sure to return 'os' in your overload function

Comment: @Nim :  the copy constructor??? now im really confused. why the copy construtor???

Comment: @jose, because when you pass by (or return by) value, you are effectively creating a copy of the object, and normally in C++ a copy is created via the copy constructor. You **really** need to go back to your C++ book and may be start off by trying to understand the purpose of the different types of constructors... create a simpler example, and in it, return some object `foo`, implement the copy constructor for `foo`, and see what happens when you return by value or a reference.

Answer (score 3):

`ostream` is not a copyable type.

Comment: @jose: when you return an object by value the return value of the function is a temporary copy of whatever you return. Here's a fairly readable comparison of the difference between return-by-value (copy), return-by-reference, and return-by-address (pointer): http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/  Note: I haven't studied the tutorial in-depth; I make no claims about the overall quality of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ostream` is `noncopyable` class. This is by design, just like threads and other concepts that are noncopyable.

Comment: and what happen inside?? please i need a more "for noob" answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you override operator<< it will look like something approximating this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, class n)
{
    os << n.some_data() << n.some_other_data(); 

    return os;
}
```

If you dont return the ostream as a reference, you wont be able to do this:

```
n myclass;
std::cout << myclass << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type has to be a reference to the same stream os so that you can chain calls together. For example:

```
out << "hello" << " " << "world";
```

If it wasn't a reference, the return type would be a value. Each value is a different stream, and so "hello" and "world" would go to different places. The *references* all *refer* to the same identical stream, so "hello" and "world" get output to the same place.

Comment: yes but i dont want to make chain calls. i just want to know why i cant do something like this using that operator:   cout<<class;      I know it doesnt even compile. thats what i want to know